# Distinguish between single and double click events in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I have a `QAbstractItemView` that needs to react to single and double click events. The actions are different depending on whether it was single clicked or double clicked. The problem that is occurring is that the single click event is received prior to the double click event.

Is there a recommended way/best practice for distinguishing between the two? I don't want to perform the single click action when the user has actually double clicked.

I am using Qt 4.6

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find answer in the thread titled [*Double Click Capturing*](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/7858-Double-Click-Capturing) on [QtCentre](http://qtcentre.org) forum;

> You could have a timer. Start the
>   timer in the releaseEvent handler and
>   make sure the timeout is long enough
>   to handle the double click first.
>   Then, in the double click event
>   handler you can stop the timer and
>   prevent it from firing. If a double
>   click handler is not triggered, the
>   timer will timeout and call a slot of
>   your choice, where you can handle the
>   single click. This is of course a
>   nasty hack, but has a chance to work.
>
> *wysota*

Comment: It works, but of course it creates a delay in the user experience when single-clicking. Whatever should happen on single-click will appear to take a "long" time (QApplication::doubleClickInterval()), so the application seems slow. Not that I can think of a better solution though, apart from Bill's answer.

Answer (score 12):

It's a good UI design to make sure your single-clicks and double-clicks are conceptually related:

```
Single-Click: select icon
Double-Click: select icon and open it

Single-Click: select color
Double-Click: select color and open palette editor
```

Notice how in these examples the single-click action is actually a subset of the double-click.  This means you can go ahead and do your single-click action normally and just do the additional action if the double-click comes in.

If your user interface does something like:

```
Single-Click: select icon
Double-Click: close window
```

Then you are setting your users up to fail.  Even if they remember what single-clicking does versus double-clicking all the time, it's very easy to accidentally move your mouse too far while double-clicking or wait too long.

Edit:

I'm sorry to hear that.

In that case, I found these two articles useful:

- [Logical consequences of the way
  Windows converts single-clicks into
  double-clicks](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/10/15/242761.aspx)
- [Implementing
  higher-order clicks](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/10/18/243925.aspx)

Comment: That is a good point but, unfortunately, not my decision to make.

Comment: @Bill: I disagree, I believe there are valid UI designs where you need to distinguish the two clicks.

E.g.
<single-click>: stop the audio player, show info on selected item.
<double-click>: same as single-click: plus play the selected item.

If you can't distinguish them, both are fired, and if the single-click is executed after the double-click, then the audio player will be stopped.

Comment: @e1i45: Have you seen the double-click event arriving before the single-click? That sounds very unlikely, since the OS will not be able to tell it's a double-click action until after the single-click has been delivered.

Comment: @Bill, no I haven't. However, Qt/Windows I've seen the following events triggered for each double click: single click, double click, single click. Which makes it necessary that the double click blocks the next single click.

Answer (score 0):

Using PySide which is the Python binding of Qt 4.8 I saw that single clicks deliver a `QEvent.MouseButtonPress` event and double clicks deliver a single `QEvent.MouseButtonPress` event closely followed by a `QEvent.MouseButtonDblClick`. The delay is approximately about `100ms` on Windows. That means you still have a problem if you need to differentiate between single and double clicks.

The solution needs another `QTimer` with a slightly higher delay than the inbuilt delay (adding some overhead). If you observe a `QEvent.MouseButtonPress` event you start your own timer, in case of timeout it is a single click. In case of a `QEvent.MouseButtonDblClick` it is a double click and you stop the timer to avoid counting as single click.