# How to distinguish between mouseReleaseEvent and mousedoubleClickEvent on QGraphicsScene

Tags: qt, pyside

I am overriden `QGraphicsScene` and overload 2 methods: `mouseDoubleClickEvent` and `mouseReleaseEvent`. I want different logic executing on each of this event, but I do not know how to distinguish it? At least 1 `mouseReleaseEvent` occured before `mouseDoubleClickEvent`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Distinguish between single and double click events in Qt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627347/distinguish-between-single-and-double-click-events-in-qt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the logic that you want to occur on a double click, put the code inside `mouseDoubleClickEvent()` and for the logic that you want to occur on a mouse release, put the code inside `mouseReleaseEvent()`.

If you want to do something when the user clicks but doesn't double click, you have to wait to see if they click twice or not. On the first mouse release start a 200ms timer.

If you get a `mouseDoubleClickEvent()` before the timer expires then it was a double click and you can do the double click logic. If the timer expires before you get another `mouseDoubleClick()` then you know it was a single click.

Pseudocode

```
main()
{
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(singleClick()));
}

mouseReleaseEvent()
{
    timer->start();
}

mouseDoubleClickEvent()
{
    timer->stop();
}

singleClick()
{
    // Do single click behavior
}
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4627517/446554) answer gives a rather similar solution.

Comment: I am using mouseReleaseEvent only due one reason - there is not event mouseClickEvent. I want some logic executed on single click and other - on double click. So I cannot use your solution - it is already implemented and not sufficient.