# Differentiate single click from double click in pyside

Tags: python, click, pyside, double-click

I have tried to implement in Pyside the method described in [How to distinguish between mouseReleaseEvent and mousedoubleClickEvent on QGrapnhicsScene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18021691/how-to-distinguish-between-mousereleaseevent-and-mousedoubleclickevent-on-qgrapn), but I had to add a crufty flag to keep it from showing single click after the second button release in a double click.

Is there a better way?

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        """an attempt to implement 
        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18021691/how-to-distinguish-between-mousereleaseevent-and-mousedoubleclickevent-on-qgrapn
        main()
            connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(singleClick()));
        mouseReleaseEvent()
            timer->start();
        mouseDoubleClickEvent()
            timer->stop();
        singleClick()
            // Do single click behavior
        """
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.setSingleShot(True)
        # had to add a "double_clicked" flag
        self.double_clicked = False
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.singleClick)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Single click, double click')    
        self.show()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if not self.double_clicked:
            self.timer.start(200)
        else:
            self.double_clicked = False

    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event):
        self.timer.stop()
        self.double_clicked = True
        print 'double click'

    def singleClick(self):
        print 'singleClick'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, as you've discovered, the original description is incomplete.

It gives a solution for distinguishing between the *first* click of a double-click and single-click, but not the *second* click of a double-click and a single-click.

The simplest solution for distinguishing the second click is to use a flag.

PS: you could slightly improve your example by using [QtGui.qApp.doubleClickInterval](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#doubleClickInterval-prop) for the timer interval.