# DoubleClick on QLabel

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

I have read this [How to distinguish between mouseReleaseEvent and mousedoubleClickEvent on QGrapnhicsScene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18021691/how-to-distinguish-between-mousereleaseevent-and-mousedoubleclickevent-on-qgrapn) and this [Distinguish between single and double click events in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627347/distinguish-between-single-and-double-click-events-in-qt/4627517#4627517) in order to solve my problem. But they do not work. I created a class QLabel:

mouselabel.h

```
#ifndef MOUSELABEL_H
#define MOUSELABEL_H

#include <QLabel>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QEvent>
#include <QDebug>


class MouseLabel : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MouseLabel(QWidget *parent = 0);
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
    void mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
    void leaveEvent(QMouseEvent *);

    int x, y;

signals:
    void Mouse_Pressed();
    void Mouse_Position();
    void Mouse_Left();
    void Mouse_Release();
    void Mouse_DoubleClick();

public slots:

};

#endif // MOUSELABEL_H
```

mouselabel.cpp

```
#include "mouselabel.h"

MouseLabel::MouseLabel(QWidget *parent) :
    QLabel(parent)
{
}


void MouseLabel::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event) {
    this->x = event->x();
    this->y = event->y();
    emit Mouse_Position();
}

void MouseLabel::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    emit Mouse_Pressed();
}

void MouseLabel::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    emit Mouse_Release();
}

void MouseLabel::mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    emit Mouse_DoubleClick();
}

void MouseLabel::leaveEvent(QMouseEvent *)
{
    emit Mouse_Left();
}
```

As described in the two links, in order to distinguish between a click and a double click, I created a timer and it starts when a mouserelease event happens and it stops when there is a double click mouse. But, this does not work. Can you help me to solve the problem?

Comment: I would investigate why the supported solution does not work for you instead of re-inventing your own solution.

Answer (score 0):

The lightest possible solution is using a `QBasicTimer`, just have those 2 methods overloaded and the timer in your widget:

```
  void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *) {
    if (timer.isActive()) {
        timer.stop();
        qDebug() << "double click";
      }
    else {
        timer.start(300, this);
      }
  }

  void timerEvent(QTimerEvent *) {
    timer.stop();
    qDebug() << "single click";
  }

  QBasicTimer timer;
```

The downside is a timer approach delays the single click, which is kind of annoying, but you could mask that, for example for selecting objects, using the `mousePressEvent` for immediate response.