# How to read double click with eventFilter?

Tags: python, qt, events, pyside

I have an eventFilter on my custom label and I would like to sniff double clicks with it. Is this possible?

```
    self.installEventFilter(self)

# Handles mouse events
def eventFilter(self, object, event):

    try:
        if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:

            #LeftButton event

        else:
            # nothing is being pressed
    except:
        pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible but for some strange reason it is not that simple. Surely you never know if a single click might be followed by another single click effectively resulting in a double click. That's why there must be some inbuilt waiting time. Qt does it and delivers events for double clicks (`QEvent.MouseButtonDblClick`). On the other hand Qt still delivers events for single clicks (`QEvent.MouseButtonPress`) even in the case of a double click, but only one. This might not be the best design.

We must differentiate them correctly. I do it with an additional timer that needs to be a bit longer than the inbuilt Qt timer for detecting double clicks. The code then goes:

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class MyLabel(QtGui.QLabel):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.installEventFilter(self)
        self.single_click_timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.single_click_timer.setInterval(200)
        self.single_click_timer.timeout.connect(self.single_click)

    def single_click(self):
        self.single_click_timer.stop()
        print('timeout, must be single click')

    def eventFilter(self, object, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
            self.single_click_timer.start()
            return True
        elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonDblClick:
            self.single_click_timer.stop()
            print('double click')
            return True

        return False


app = QtGui.QApplication([])

window = MyLabel('Click me')
window.resize(200, 200)
window.show()

app.exec_()
```

See also [Distinguish between single and double click events in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627347/distinguish-between-single-and-double-click-events-in-qt).